# VSCode, Anaconda on MacOS. Module not found (Pandas and Numpy for eg.)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, visual-studio-code, anaconda

So I installed vscode and anaconda on macos. I'm not a very experienced programmer and I can't figure out what is wrong. When I try to import numpy or pandas it says module not found. Any help to get this working is appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

In VSCode you need to specify the interpreter you want to use to run your code. To do so, either click the button next to "Python" in the bottom right of the UI or search (CMD shift P) "Python: select interpreter," then select the right interpreter / environment you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have the [python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) installed.
2. Make sure that you have installed these two packages. You can use command `pip list` in the terminal to view, or directly use `pip install numpy` and `pip install pandas` to install the packages.
3. If the second step doesn't work, choose the Python interpreter correctly in vscode:

Use the `Ctrl+Shift+P` command, search for and select `Python:Select Interpreter`(Or click directly on the python version displayed in the lower right corner), and select the correct interpreter.

[image]